# Benefit of adding policy and value loss in actor-critic?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, loss-functions

Is there an benefit of adding the value and policy loss together in an actor-critic setting?

In the original A3C paper in Algorithm S3 it says to apply both gradients separate but I have seen people adding the loss and getting a combined gradient instead.

Does that make a difference? Why? What are the advantages and disadvantages?